# Как настроить полнотекстовый поиск по заказам и контактам на PostgreSQL?

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, полнотекстовый-поиск, crm

Я разрабатываю SaaS решение CRM системы. На всех клиентов одна БД. На стадии запуска не хотелось бы использовать отдельные поисковые движки для FTS, пока использую возможности PgSQL.

## Задача 1

Нужно уметь искать клиента по Фамилии, Имени, Номеру телефона, Емейлу.
Номер телефона состоит из двух полей: phone_country_id и phone_number (код страны и телефон). Эту задачу я буду решать собрав предварительно данные до кучи и при создании записи в БД построю для нее поисковый индекс.
Например так:
'Пупкин Вася':A, '+12223334455':B, 'vasya@pupkin.tt':C

Правильно ли мое решение?
Подходит ли FTS для моей задачи?
Есть ли словари для русского и английского языка для поиска по именам и фамилиям? Или это бред? :)

## Задача 2

Нужно уметь искать заказы по любому полю из пункта 1 и еще по ряду полей из таблицы заказа (номер заказа, дата создания, источник, и тд.).
В заказ с пользователем связывает только одно поле - consumer_id.

В качестве решения я выбрал подход из 2 запросов:

1. Найти всех клиентов по заранее заготовленному индексу в таблице клиента.
2. Выбрать все заказы найденных клиентов и отфильтровать их по остальным полям.

Если поиск идет по номеру заказа, все остальные атрибуты не учитываются.

В правильном ли направлении я двигаюсь?
Было ли что-то упущенно в построенной мной логике?

Comment: В сторону интеграции с sphinxsearch не смотрели?

Comment: Я же написал, что на первой стадии запуска это накладно.

Comment: Накладно в каком плане, ресурсы скушает?

Comment: Время на интерграцию и поддержку еще одного звена системы, ну и ресурсы тоже. Сложность системы так же возростает)

Comment: Для этого есть Docker. Поднимается образ одной командой, инкапсуляция, не прожорлив.

Comment: У вас два вопроса в одном. Разделите.